# Why does running my HTML page from a server cause parts of it to be cut off

Tags: html

I made an HTML page for my uni assignment, and when I run it locally from my files it works fine and looks like this: [image: working page]

However, when I run it off of a server in vs code it ends up looking like this

[image: cut off page]

For some reason the part of the first section has been cut off.
When I reload the page for a brief millisecond the page will look how it should, and then it will return to being cut off.

I have a JS script file for this page and have tried to turn it off to see if that caused it but still same issue

I'm really lost with this any help will be appreciated,
please let me know if you need to see the code I haven't included it in this initially as I didn't want to put a big wall of code

Thanks :)

```js
"use strict";
/*************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
functions for apply.html to validate date of birth, postcode, and text box
**********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
//function to get the age of an applicant
function getAge() {
  var age = -1;
  const yearInMs = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var nowdate = new Date();
  var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
  var dayMonthYear = dob.split("/");
  var dobsplt = new Date(dayMonthYear[2], dayMonthYear[1], dayMonthYear[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);
  age = (nowdate.valueOf() - dobsplt.valueOf()) / yearInMs;
  return age;
}
//function to check the age of an applicant
function checkAge() {
  var result = false;
  var gottenage = getAge();
  if (gottenage > 18 < 50) {
    result = true;
  } else {
    result = false;
    alert("You have to be between 18 and 50 to apply for this role.");
  }
  return result;
}
//function to validate an applicants date of birth
function validateDob() {
  var date = document.getElementById("dob");
  var result = false;
  // regex for date sourced from: https://www.regextester.com/?fam=114662
  // method from lecture
  var pattern = /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([1][26]|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g;
  if (pattern.test(date.value)) {
    result = true;
  } else {
    result = false;
  }
  return result;
}
// combinbed function to run checkAge() and valiateDob()
function checkDobandAge() {
  if (validateDob()) {
    getAge();
    checkAge();
  } else {
    alert("Please enter date of birth correctly");
  }
}
// function to check state against postcode
function validateState() {
  var result = false
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
  var postcode = document.getElementById("postc").value;
  var firstpost = postcode.charAt(0);
  var checkpost = (firstpost + state);
  const viccheck = "3VIC";
  const viccheck2 = "8VIC";
  const nswcheck = "1NSW";
  const nswcheck2 = "2NSW";
  const qldcheck = "4QLD";
  const qldcheck2 = "9QLD";
  const ntcheck = "0NT";
  const wacheck = "6WA";
  const sacheck = "5SA";
  const tascheck = "7TAS";
  const actcheck = "0ACT";
  if (checkpost.match(viccheck) || checkpost.match(viccheck2) || checkpost.match(nswcheck) || checkpost.match(nswcheck2) || checkpost.match(qldcheck) ||
    checkpost.match(qldcheck2) || checkpost.match(ntcheck) || checkpost.match(wacheck) || checkpost.match(sacheck) || checkpost.match(tascheck) || checkpost.match(actcheck)) {
    result = true;
  } else {
    result = false;
  }
  return result;
}
//function to cause the alert when the state and post code mismatches
function alertState() {
  var result = false
  if (validateState()) {
    result = true;
  } else {
    alert("Wrong state bozo")
    result = false;
  }
  return result;
}
//function to insert text into textbox upon refresh
function insertText() {
  var textAT = document.getElementById("othertext");
  textAT.value = "Please enter any other skills here"
}
//function to deletetext
function deleteText() {
  var textAT = document.getElementById("othertext");
  textAT.value = textAT.value.replace("Please enter any other skills here", "")
}
//function to check if the otherskills is filled in when the checkbox is clicked
function checkOtherSkills() {
  var result = false;
  var otherSkillsChecked = document.getElementById("other2").checked;
  var otherSkillsbox = document.getElementById("othertext").value;
  if (otherSkillsChecked) {
    var boxChecked = "yes";
  } else {
    var boxChecked = "no";
  }
  if (otherSkillsbox != "") {
    var boxEmpty = "no";
  } else {
    var boxEmpty = "yes";
  }
  var otherSkillsComplete = boxChecked + boxEmpty;
  if (otherSkillsComplete.match("yesno")) {
    result = true;
  }
  if (otherSkillsComplete.match("noyes")) {
    result = true;
  }
  if (otherSkillsComplete.match("nono")) {
    result = true;
  }
  if (otherSkillsComplete.match("yesyes")) {
    alert("Please enter Other skills");
  }
  return result;
}
// code to get gender 
function getGender() {
  var gender = "Unknown";
  var genderArray = document.getElementById("gender").getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < genderArray.length; i++) {
    if (genderArray[i].checked)
      gender = genderArray[i].value;
  }
  return gender;
}
// code for storing applicant info for the session (checkbox and radio button method from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912415/persisting-multiple-checkbox-states-in-session-storage)
function storeInfo() {
  var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
  var addr = document.getElementById("addr").value;
  var suburb = document.getElementById("sub").value;
  var postcode = document.getElementById("postc").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("pno").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var skillstext = document.getElementById("othertext").value;
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
  var prog = document.getElementById("prog").checked;
  var prog2 = document.getElementById("prog2").checked;
  var debug = document.getElementById("debug").checked;
  var cad2 = document.getElementById("cad2").checked;
  var cpp = document.getElementById("cpp").checked;
  var api = document.getElementById("api").checked;
  var wav = document.getElementById("wav").checked;
  var prob = document.getElementById("prob").checked;
  var sec = document.getElementById("sec").checked;
  var inc = document.getElementById("inc").checked;
  var other2 = document.getElementById("other2").checked;
  var male = document.getElementById("male").checked;
  var fmale = document.getElementById("fmale").checked;
  var other = document.getElementById("other").checked;
  sessionStorage.setItem("fname", firstname);
  sessionStorage.setItem("lname", lastname);
  sessionStorage.setItem("dob", dob);
  sessionStorage.setItem("addr", addr);
  sessionStorage.setItem("sub", suburb);
  sessionStorage.setItem("postc", postcode);
  sessionStorage.setItem("phone", phone);
  sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);
  sessionStorage.setItem("skillstext", skillstext);
  sessionStorage.setItem("state", state);
  sessionStorage.setItem("prog", prog);
  sessionStorage.setItem("prog2", prog2);
  sessionStorage.setItem("debug", debug);
  sessionStorage.setItem("cad2", cad2);
  sessionStorage.setItem("cpp", cpp);
  sessionStorage.setItem("api", api);
  sessionStorage.setItem("wav", wav);
  sessionStorage.setItem("prob", prob);
  sessionStorage.setItem("sec", sec);
  sessionStorage.setItem("inc", inc);
  sessionStorage.setItem("other2", other2);
  sessionStorage.setItem("male", male);
  sessionStorage.setItem("fmale", fmale);
  sessionStorage.setItem("other", other);

}
//validation function 
function validate() {
  checkDobandAge();
  alertState();
  checkOtherSkills();
  storeInfo();
}
//function to load all stored applicant form values upon webpage reloading 
function loadvalues() {
  document.getElementById("fname").value = sessionStorage.getItem('fname');
  document.getElementById("lname").value = sessionStorage.getItem('lname');
  document.getElementById("dob").value = sessionStorage.getItem('dob');
  document.getElementById("addr").value = sessionStorage.getItem('addr');
  document.getElementById("sub").value = sessionStorage.getItem('sub');
  document.getElementById("postc").value = sessionStorage.getItem('postc');
  document.getElementById("pno").value = sessionStorage.getItem('phone');
  document.getElementById("email").value = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
  document.getElementById("othertext").value = sessionStorage.getItem('skillstext');
  document.getElementById("state").value = sessionStorage.getItem('state')
  if (sessionStorage.prog == "true") {
    document.getElementById("prog").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.prog2 == "true") {
    document.getElementById("prog2").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.debug == "true") {
    document.getElementById("debug").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.cad2 == "true") {
    document.getElementById("cad2").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.cpp == "true") {
    document.getElementById("cpp").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.api == "true") {
    document.getElementById("api").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.wav == "true") {
    document.getElementById("wav").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.prob == "true") {
    document.getElementById("prob").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.sec == "true") {
    document.getElementById("sec").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.inc == "true") {
    document.getElementById("inc").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.other2 == "true") {
    document.getElementById("other2").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.male == "true") {
    document.getElementById("male").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.fmale == "true") {
    document.getElementById("fmale").checked = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.other == "true") {
    document.getElementById("other").checked = true;
  }
}

//function to change webpage
function changewb() {
  window.location.href = "apply.html"
}
//functions to retrieve job reference number upon clicking apply stored in local storage (substring method: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)
function storeCloud() {
  var strCloudJRN = document.getElementById("cloudJRN").textContent;
  var cloudJRN = strCloudJRN.substring(27);
  localStorage.setItem('jrn', cloudJRN)
  changewb();
}

function storeCyber() {
  var strCyberJRN = document.getElementById("cyberJRN").textContent;
  var cyberJRN = strCyberJRN.substring(27);
  localStorage.setItem('jrn', cyberJRN);
  changewb();
}
//function to paste the stored JRN into the specific field of the form
function pasteCloud() {
  var reference = document.getElementById("ref");
  reference.value = localStorage.getItem('jrn');
  document.getElementById('ref').readOnly = true;
}


function init() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('apply.html') > -1) {
    var otherSkillsChecked = document.getElementById("other2");
    var textbox = document.getElementById("othertext")
    var regform = document.getElementById("regform");
    otherSkillsChecked.onclick = deleteText;
    textbox.onclick = deleteText;
    regform.onsubmit = validate;
    pasteCloud();
    loadvalues();
    insertText();
  }
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('jobs.html') > -1) {
    var cloudbutton = document.getElementById("cloudbutton");
    var jcabutton = document.getElementById("jcabutton");
    cloudbutton.onclick = storeCloud;
    jcabutton.onclick = storeCyber;
  }
}
window.onload = init;
```

```css
/*=======================================================================================================
    jobs.html style code
    ========================================================================================================*/

* {
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  font: 50px sans-serif, normal;
}

#ar {
  text-align: center;
}

#cad,
#jca {
  background-color: #190036;
  width: 73.5%;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

#adtext,
#jcatext {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 10px;
}

#adlists,
#jcalist {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

aside {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: solid #d6b1ff;
  background: blueviolet;
  border-radius: 5%;
  float: right;
  word-break: normal;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}

div#uni {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  float: right;
  word-break: normal;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 5%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

div#uni img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}

div#uni img#dulogo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#gr,
#cloudhead #jcahead {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*=======================================================================================================
    jobs.html style
    Button style
    method from: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp
    ========================================================================================================*/

#cloudbutton,
#jcabutton {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border: blueviolet;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/*=======================================================================================================
    apply.html style
    ========================================================================================================*/

#appn {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}

fieldset {
  border: solid blueviolet;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #190036;
}

fieldset label {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

textarea {
  background: blueviolet;
}

.gender,
.contactinfo,
.skills {
  border: blueviolet dotted;
}

fieldset input[type=text],
fieldset input[type=email],
fieldset input[type=date],
fieldset select {
  background-color: #190036;
  border: solid blueviolet;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px 2.5px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

input[type=radio],
fieldset input[type=checkbox] {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

input[type=submit],
input[type=reset] {
  background-color: #190036;
  border: solid blueviolet;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

input[type=submit]:hover,
input[type=reset]:hover {
  background: blueviolet;
  transition: .5s;
}

fieldset legend {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

input[type=radio],
fieldset input[type=checkbox],
fieldset input[type=date] {
  z-index: 1;
}

.error {
  color: #af4242;
  background-color: #fde8ec;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.error.display-error {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Head -->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Job listing website for IT roles">
  <meta name="author" content="Omar Al-angurli">
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="apply.js">
  </script>
  <title> Apply page for PeakIT </title>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Nav bar code(enhancement: most work performed in CSS)  -->
  <nav class="navbar">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check" class="checkbtn"> &#8801; </label>
    <label class="logo" id="navlogo"> PeakIT </label>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a id="home" href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
      <li><a id="about" href="about.html">About Me </a></li>
      <li><a id="apply" href="apply.html"> Apply now</a> </li>
      <li><a id="jobs" href="jobs.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a id="enhancements" href="enhancements.html">Enhancements</a></li>
      <li><a id="contact" href=mailto:104467971@student.swin.edu.au> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- Form section -->
  <h1 id="appn"> Apply Now </h1>
  <form id="regform" novalidate="novalidate">
    <p class="success application-success"></p>
    <p class="error application-error"></p>
    <fieldset class="fjrn">
      <p>
        <label for="ref"> Job Reference Number </label>
        <input type="text" name="job reference number" id="ref" required="required">
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="jrn" id="jrn" /> see comments in JS file to explain why this is hidden action="https://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php"-->
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fad">
      <legend> Applicant Details </legend>
      <p>
        <label for="fname"> First Name </label>
        <input type="text" name="First Name" id="fname" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{0,20}">
        <label for="lname"> Last Name </label>
        <input type="text" name="Last Name" id="lname" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{0,20}">
        <label for="dob"> Date of Birth </label>
        <input type="text" name="Date of Birth" id="dob" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
        <span class="error dob-error"></span>
      </p>
      <fieldset id="gender">
        <legend> Gender </legend>
        <p>
          <label for="male"> Male </label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" required="required" value="male">
          <label for="fmale"> Female </label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="fmale" value="female">
          <label for="other"> Other </label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="other">
        </p>
      </fieldset>
      <p>
        <label for="addr"> Street Address </label>
        <input type="text" name="Street address" id="addr" required="required" maxlength="40">
        <label for="sub"> Suburb / Town </label>
        <input type="text" name="Suburb / town" id="sub" required="required" maxlength="40">
        <label for="postc"> Postcode </label>
        <input type="text" name="Postcode" id="postc" pattern="[0-9\S]{4}">
        <label for="state"> State </label>
        <select name="state" id="state">
          <option value=""> Please Select </option>
          <option value="VIC"> VIC </option>
          <option value="QLD"> QLD </option>
          <option value="NSW"> NSW </option>
          <option value="ACT"> ACT </option>
          <option value="NT"> NT</option>
          <option value="WA"> WA </option>
          <option value="SA"> SA </option>
          <option value="TAS"> TAS </option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <fieldset class="contactinfo">
        <legend> Contact Information </legend>
        <p>
          <label for="pno"> Phone Number </label>
          <input type="text" name="phone number" id="pno" required="required" pattern="[0-9\s]{8,12}">
          <label for="email"> Email Address </label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required">
        </p>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="skills">
        <legend> Skills </legend>
        <p>
          <label for="prog"> Proficiency in one programming language </label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="Proficiency in programming" id="prog" checked="checked" required="required">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="prog2"> Proficiency in two or more programming language </label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="Proficiency in programming" id="prog2">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="debug"> Debugging and troubelshooting</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="debugging and troubleshooting" id="debug">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="cad2"> Cloud application development</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="Cloud application development" id="cad2">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="cpp"> Proficiency in one or more cloud based platform </label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="Proficiency in Cloud based platforms" id="cpp">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="api"> API development </label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="API development" id="api">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="wav"> Written and verbal skills </label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="written and verbal skills" id="wav">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="prob"> Problem solving skills </label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="Problem solving" id="prob">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="sec"> Security analysis </label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="Security analysis" id="sec">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="inc"> Incidence response </label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="incidence response" id="inc">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="other2"> Other </label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="other" id="other2">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="othertext"> Please enter any other skills here </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <textarea id="othertext" name="othertext" rows="6" cols="100"> Please enter any other skills here</textarea>
        </p>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitform">
        <input type="reset">
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <section id="bottom">
      <footer>
        <h2> PeakIT</h2>
        <p> &#169;Copyright 2023. - Crafted by Omar Al-angurli </p>
        <p id="cm"> <a href=mailto:104467971@student.swin.edu.au> Contact Me</a> </p>
        <br>
        <p id="hp"><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></p>
        <p id="am"><a href="about.html">About Me </a></p>
        <p id="ap"><a href="apply.html"> Apply now</a> </p>
        <p id="jo"><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></p>
        <p id="enh"><a href="enhancements.html">Enhancements</a></p>
      </footer>
    </section>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please include the files. You may provide external links to avoid cluttering the question.

Comment: Assuming this page uses css, are the css files being loaded correctly?

Comment: @Kitswas, i have added the code, let me know if you need the CSS as well

Comment: @John Gordon i assume so? all the other css on this and the other webpages seems to be working fine,  and it works fine when i load the file up not on a server

Comment: @OmarAlangurli http://127.0.0.1:5500/jobs.html is a local link. It won't work on the internet.

Comment: @OmarAlangurli Edit the post. Press Ctrl+M (or click on the Insert HTML/CSS/JS button). Then paste your code in the relevant sections there.

Comment: Go to `View > Source` in the browser. Then find the link to your CSS and Javascript files. Click on those links. Do the links open?

Comment: @kitswas done, i only included the CSS code for the page as there was a character limit i was exceeding

Comment: @kojow7 yeah just checked they are opening fine

Comment: I have also just discovered when i open it on firefox its fine, but chrome is where it messes up

Comment: Have you tried HTML, CSS, and JavaScript validators?

Comment: @OmarAlangurli Try https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload

Comment: Please learn about what a [mcve] is and edit your question to include one